# Responsive column jumps on specific width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, multiple-columns

This is my first question over here, I searched the site but I really couldn't find a decent answer. My problem is pretty specific.

On full resolution my homepage consists of four columns, however, when the window-width gets below 960, it transforms in to two columns, this is the code I used:

The HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="begin col14">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="begin col14">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        Content
    </div>
  <div class="begin col14">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      Content
  </div>
  <div class="begin col14">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      Content
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
    .begin {
        width:46%;
        margin:0px 2% 2em 2%;
        float:left;
    }
}
```

The problem is only showing on a browser-width of around 619px, then the first column on the second row jumps to the next row.

For an example, please check: www.visiamedia.nl

I hope someone can help me out, it really bothers me.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your boxes are different heights when resized - and first one is pushing other floats aside. You could potentially fix the issue by setting a media query with a specific height between about 515px to 640px:

```
@media all and (min-width: 515px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    .begin {
        height: 190px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a width of `46%`. Change it to `21%`

```
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
    .begin {
        width:21%;
        margin:0px 2% 2em 2%;
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't put it clear, it's meant to change into a two column website

so I use :
    
    width:50%; 

and 

    padding:2%;

to make sure one column takes up 50% of the available space.

Comment: I just visited your website and it seems fine the way it's switching at different resolutions. I don't follow what your problem is.

Comment: It switches nicely indeed, but the jump happens on a browser width of about 620px only (and changes back nicely after getting wider or smaller). Here's an example: http://postimg.org/image/i5tgfx3w5/

Comment: After looking at it again it came to my mind, while the width of the columns changed (when the browser was resized) the text inside of them changed in height. The problem occurred when WEBDESIGN and HUISSTIJLEN both had a different height.

I fixed the problem by surrounding both groups of div in a container div, and adding

    clear:both;

on that div when the browser became smaller than 960px;

Thanks a lot for the responses anyway!